# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (React.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Well, basically, I'm since yesterday trying to understand with .map keeps coming as undefined. I'm trying to reach inside **area_set** the **name** propertie.
I will write down below the console.log of **this.state.model** which I'm trying to access:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "brand": {...},
    "couchmodelfile_set": [...],
    "area_set": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "couch_model": 1,
            "name": "Area 1",
            "dimensions_price": [
                {
                    "dimensions": "96",
                    "seat": 54,
                    "arm": 21,
                    "price_table_code": "table_1",
                    "prices": []
                },
                {
                    id: 7, ...
                }...
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, this is the code inside my render method:

```
export class Sofa extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        token: {},
        isLoaded: false,
        model: {}
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    /* Fetch to get token from API */

    fetch(url + '/couch-model/1/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({
            model: json
        }, () => {
            console.log('model: ', json);
        });
    })

}


render() {

    const { model, isLoaded } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {

        return (
            <div id="LoadText">
                Estamos a preparar o seu sofá!
            </div>
        )

    } else {

        return (
                    <div id="Esquerda">

                        <h2>{/* show area_set */}</h2>

                        <h1>{model.name}</h1>
                        <p>Highly durable full-grain leather which is soft and has  a natural look and feel.</p>

                        <h3>Design</h3>
                        <h4>Hexagon</h4>
                    </div>
        );

    }

  }

}
```

And by the way, the `.map` that is in the code above it's not working...
I really need some help to get out of this one :(

Comment: You have `model.layout_set.map` in your code. But should it be `model.area_set.map`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but that's not the problem, doesn't work anyways :( @thesilkworm

Comment: Try doing `console.log(this.state)` as the first line of your render function, to make sure the data is where you think it is.

Comment: How do you populate the state? Please, write a working code with all the needed parts defined. We need the element constructor as is the first point where the state should be populated.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EwfRRIg this image that is equal to the json in my question is the console.log of this.state.model @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: That is the json of that console.log @thesilkworm

Comment: There is no matching `]` for `"dimensions_price": [`.  Is that true? Would you validate your json string?  You can validate here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Still no constructor code... Are you sure the `console.log(this.state)` don't throws an empty null or undefined before throwing the valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, it comes empty twice and only then comes with an answer @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: Then show us your constructor, by third time, please. The state should be populated on costruction, with empty data at least. If you have an undefined state, then it will fail to access the state as is non existent.

Comment: .map issue will be solved as earlier

Comment: Is not working because you never set `isLoaded` to `true`. Is always `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state model is empty on construction. The render method is called BEFORE the ajax request ends, so the render method is trying to access an empty model.

You can prevent it in two ways. To check if model is empty and render another thing, or to populate the state with a valid model while the ajax request is being loaded.

EDIT: Now you simply have to set `isLoaded` to `true` along with the model when ajax ends.

Answer (score 0):

In your object definition there is:

```
"area_set": [...]
```

and you are trying to access

```
{model.layout_set.map
```

Change it to area_set.map(....) and it should work ;)

Comment: Not really, sorry, pasted the code I was trying to make it work. Changed that and doesn't work still :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following way.You need to check whether the state(modal) is empty on render method for proper working of `map`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal:[]

    };
  }

  render() {
    const  {modal}  = this.state;
    return (
      {modal ?
      <div id="Esquerda">
        {modal.area_set.map(layout =>
        <div>
          <h2>{layout.id}</h2>
          <h1>{layout.name}</h1>
          </div>
        )}

        <p>Highly durable full-grain leather which is soft and has  a natural look and feel.</p>
        <h3>Design</h3>
        <h4>Hexagon</h4>
      </div>
      :<div>No data</div>}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an example on how to populate the state on construction, so the render method will have something to access while you populate it with valid data elsewhere.

Comment: what is your requirement,from your question it is not clear

Comment: i have included the check for empty state,if you are populating the state from an api call.Please do check